# React js Multiple drag and drop items

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I get 2 list(left and right) and I'm tring to drag and drop Multiple items, I added one `input type="checkBox"` for select, and drag/drop.

[image]

you can see that I added one `checkBox` to each item, this is for select, I can select multiple items simultaneously, and then I can drag and drop to list right.

so currently I'm getting one issue, if I a selected multiple items by `checkBox` and I'll try to drag and drop to the left list I got this issue:

`Error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, checked, array}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

so I update the `drag` function  on component `Item.js`, but I'm getting the same error.

what's wrong?? what can I do for select several items and drag and drop in list right??

I have the code on [codesandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-aj-7gy97s?file=/src/App.js)

I found this simple example [Drag and Drop Simple](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-multi-select-list-forked-cs7cvp?file=/src/App.js), I tried to adapt on my code, but not work.

The simple exampe([Drag and Drop Simple](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-multi-select-list-forked-cs7cvp?file=/src/App.js)) work for array of string, but my array is of object